# Javafx (Node) getUserDate() or getProperties() returns a none null value and throws NullPointerException

Tags: javafx

Here is the code that set the user data.

```
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(page.toString()));
   Parent node = (Parent) loader.load();
   loader.getController().setParent(handler);
   controllers.put(page.name(), loader.getController());
   controller = controllers.get(page.name());
   node.setUserData(page.name());
   node.getProperties().put("page", page.name());
```

the variable page is an Enum object, I'm using the name 'page.name()' as the user data

Here is the code that gets the user data:

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Node node = iterator.next();
        String name = node.getProperties().get("page").toString();
        System.out.println(name);
        ....
    }
```

now this what happens:
the **System.out.println(name);** prints out the user data correctly,
and then I get a **NullPointException** pointing to

```
String name = node.getProperties().get("page").toString();
```

the point is **System.out.println(name);** that prints the user date
prints it correct.

What's going on here?

Comment: Surely this just means that on the first iteration through the loop you are pointing to the `Node` for which the property `page` was set, and on the second iteration you are pointing to a `Node` for which is was not set, giving the Null Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down. Code is usually easier to read when you do not chain multiple method calls together.

```
Node node = iterator.next();
ObservableMap<Object, Object> properties = node.getProperties(); // Swap Object with whatever subclass it is supposed to return
Object nameProperty = properties.get("page"); // Same here
String name = nameProperty.toString();
```

Then see which line returns the null pointer exception and try searching for the reason behind it. It is likely that either getProperties() or get("page") is in fact returning a null value.